# c++ unordered_set with shared_ptr search for raw pointer

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I have a unordered_set with shared_ptrs as a key. This works fine in 99%, but in same cases I need to search the set from inside the class and I would like to avoid inheriting enable_shared_from_this, just because of that.

Can/how I search a unordered_set of shared_ptr by raw pointer.

Comment: Why on Earth are you searching on a pointer?

Comment: `std::find_if` with a custom predicate (as a lambda)?

Comment: @DanMašek: That would have pretty poor performance compared to a regular `unordered_set::find`

Comment: @DanMašek find_if does not capitalize on hash table - it will be cheaper to  create shared_ptr with null deleter over using find_if

Comment: @EdHeal I am not sure what exactly you mean, but if you imply that I am searching for the value of the pointer, I did not say that and I do not in this case. There are a lot of cases that I actually do that where for example I have a global cache that ensures uniqueness of the objects which allows for search for them by pointer which in generic case might be way cheaper to hash.

Comment: You have a set of keys 'pointers' - And you are searching them. Are you looking for a pointer of a certain value?

Comment: @EdHeal I am looking for object in the set that is the same in the sense of the hash and comparison predicates in the set, it might be same pointer value, it might not.

Comment: I do not understand why you are searching for a pointer. It already points to the same object. I think you have an XY problem

Comment: @EdHeal to check if it is in the set ... and change my algorithm outcome based on that?!?

Comment: If the pointer to the object is in the set (the object itself can register this fact) then what

Comment: It can but it does not need to - if I can simply check if the set has it or not ... and I can do this with 1000 of different sets without complicating my object.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, good point, I haven't thought it through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashing a `shared_ptr` hashes `get()` and comparing a `shared_ptr` compares `get()`, so let's just make a non-owning `shared_ptr` with the aliasing constructor:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> key(std::shared_ptr<T>(),
                       this /* or whatever pointer you want to search for */);
```

And search the `unordered_set` with that.

Compared to using a null deleter, this is cheaper as it doesn't allocate a control block.

Answer (score 3):

No, `unordered_set` does not have functions that allow you to search based on anything other than an actual instance of the `Key` type.

However, `shared_ptr<T>` has 3 important features that makes it possible to get the effect you need:

1. `std::hash<shared_ptr<T>>` is defined to be equivalent to hashing `T*`.
2. `std::shared_ptr`'s `operator==` compares the pointers based on `shared_ptr::get`.
3. You can create a `shared_ptr` that has a deleter which doesn't actually delete the object.

As such, you can create a faux `shared_ptr`:

```
T *ptr = this;
auto sp = shared_ptr<T>(ptr, [](T*) {} );
auto it = the_set.find(sp);
```

So long as `sp` doesn't escape your scope (you *really* don't want to keep it around), you'll be fine.